# What is "Woods Metal"

Tags: metallurgy

I have a piece of what I have been told is "Woods Metal" it melts at 168F.  I am "curious" about how they make it, how low can the melting temperature be?

Comment: [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood%27s_metal).

Comment: Wood's alloy is but a certain mixture of metals, and that' just how they make it: they mix the metals and melt them together. Its composition is adjusted so as to reach the lowest possible melting point. You can get beyond that if you use **mercury**, but then you'll get poisoned and die. Other than that, you would be able to reach way lower.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some additional info from web

Wood's metal, also known as Lipowitz's alloy or by the commercial names Cerrobend, Bendalloy, Pewtalloy and MCP 158, is a eutectic, fusible alloy with a melting point of approximately 70 °C (158 °F). It is a eutectic alloy of 50% bismuth, 26.7% lead, 13.3% tin, and 10% cadmium by weight.

I have experience using the material for fixturing of difficult to secure /  shaped parts for machining. It can also help in fixturing/holding - then later melted away.

The eutectic composition will privide lowest Tm and get the info from a phase diagram.

Do not add mercury for safety reasons.